# Multiple text alignment with same label using NSMutableAttributedString on iOS

Tags: ios, text-alignment, nsmutableattributedstring

I want to set Text direction for my label using `NSMutableAttributedString`. for example, I have chat view, which contains message and time. I want to set left alignment for message and right alignment for time using `UILabel`.

I have used following code, but it's not working,

```
 NSString *Time = [Functions stringFromGivenDate:msg.time withFormate:@"hh:mm a"];
 NSMutableAttributedString *str = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",msg.text,Time]];
 NSDictionary *attrDictionary = @{NSWritingDirectionAttributeName:@[@(NSTextWritingDirectionOverride)]};

[str addAttributes:attrDictionary range:NSMakeRange(msg.text.length+1, Time.length)];
```

Comment: NSWritingDirectionAttributeName need two parameters if I remember well. Check the doc.

Comment: Have you considered just using a separate label for time and a separate label for the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly, this should help:

```
 NSMutableParagraphStyle *style  = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        style.alignment = alignment;// type NSTextAlignment
        NSDictionary *attributtes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style,};
```